# Problem with SqlAlchemy when trying to run localy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

Im trying to learn a bit better how to use sqlalchemy and deploy to heroku. besides some other problems I have I decided to firstly test the app locally and then worry about deploying it but I get a few errors when trying to run it.

before running I do set the database variables and the app settings in the terminal but still I cant get it to run and continue from there.

this is the error I get from the terminal

```
(venv) C:\Users\Stratos\Desktop\test-orm>python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 11, in <module>
    from models import Result
  File "C:\Users\Stratos\Desktop\test-orm\models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import db
  File "C:\Users\Stratos\Desktop\test-orm\app.py", line 11, in <module>
    from models import Result
ImportError: cannot import name 'Result' from partially initialized module 'models' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Stratos\Desktop\test-orm\models.py)
```

and this is the error I get when I try to run it directly from vscode

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Stratos/Desktop/test-orm/app.py", line 7, in <module>
    app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
  File "c:\users\stratos\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'APP_SETTINGS'
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from models import Result


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"


@app.route('/<name>')
def hello_name(name):
    return "Hello {}!".format(name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

manage.py

```
import os
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

from app import app, db


app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])

migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

models.py

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON


class Result(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'results'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String())
    result_all = db.Column(JSON)
    result_no_stop_words = db.Column(JSON)

    def __init__(self, url, result_all, result_no_stop_words):
        self.url = url
        self.result_all = result_all
        self.result_no_stop_words = result_no_stop_words

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<id {}>'.format(self.id)
```

config.py

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    CSRF_ENABLED = True
    SECRET_KEY = 'this-really-needs-to-be-changed'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']


class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False


class StagingConfig(Config):
    DEVELOPMENT = True
    DEBUG = True


class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEVELOPMENT = True
    DEBUG = True


class TestingConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True
```

.env file

```
set APP_SETTINGS=config.DevelopmentConfig
set DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:798361!@localhost:5432/dok
```

Comment: You have a circular import - app is importing from models and models is importing from app.

Comment: well i see . i commented it out but now I get more issues. the thing is I followed a tutorial from realpython and the end goal is to deploy to heroku but for some reason I couldn't follow the tutorial per word so I improvised and searched some issues I had. for instance the tutorial was telling to set the database URL as DATABASE_URL="postgresql:///dok" but without passwords and users I couldn't migrate it so I changed it in the way It is shows above. then i had problems with heroku so i did it differently. in the end i decided to run it locally and finish the app and then worry about heroku

Comment: I have a template for apps in my repo, check it out for reference. https://github.com/rajverma1985/app_template . Also checkout my other repo https://github.com/rajverma1985/anticovidrobo which will give you an idea on db migration. Feel free to chat if you come across any other problems or not able to understand stuff in the repo(no offence).

Comment: thank you im reading it now. although I see it doesn't have a requirements text. I'll try it out in any case thanks again